# Nunjucks/Jinja - alternative for `include` when access to scope is needed

Tags: templates, jinja2, templating, nunjucks, client-side-templating

According to Nunjucks [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#include),

> an include is not a pre-processor that pulls the included template code into the including template before rendering; instead, it fires off a separate render of the included template, and the results of that render are included.

**If you actually want a "pre-processor that pulls the included template code into the including template before rendering", what that would be in Nunjucks/Jinja?**

---

Practical example would be: two partials have same variables being `set`. We decide to DRY it up, putting those `set` statements into a partial and requesting it via `include`. When using `include` those variables are out of scope.

*partial-config.nunjucks:*

```
{% set var = 'x' %}
```

*partial1.nunjucks:*

```
{% include "partial-config.nunjucks" %}
var={{ var }}
```

*partial2.nunjucks:*

```
{% include "partial-config.nunjucks" %}
var={{ var }}
```

**Challenge**: The variable `var` in partials above is blank. I want it to be set within each partial's scope, before rendering, as if it was only string snippet, without extra scopes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it's not possible because first render primary template and `include` after it. Maybe I wrong.

In any case you can use [custom loader](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#writing-a-loader), "define" your own tag e.g. `config` with usage like `{% config "filename.njk" %}`. Loader must find `config`-tag and replace this row by `filename.njk` and pass template to render next.